# Best Practice for huge nav bar

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, navigation, menu

Well I'am pretty new here. And hopes you guys out there can help me.
I have got a work to recreate a website. In that i have a menu bar which contains 17-18 main menu items. The question here is to how to design this huge menu bar. please see the link for [design](http://www.cmchistn.com/). I'am confused about the menu bar

Any suggestions will be Helpful.

Comment: You had me at scrolling text and blinking phone number. Forget the menu, it doesn't seem so bad anymore.

Comment: There is no best practice for bad design :/ Even the largest organizations like Samsung, Apple, Microsoft, ... are able to have a maximum of 7 categories in the main menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the menu:
I agree with Dave, that you could perhaps explore possibility to have it vertical, albeit you could gain more with simply restructuring and hoping you can fit all menu items in one row and still have only 2 levels.

However, another alternative would be to have the top navigation contain only the most primary and sought after links that most users are looking for. I am pretty sure you are stuffing all that information there just because you have to put it somewhere, and I don't think you have done any significant user research, card sorting or anything of that sort.

So what I'd suggest is, to **get a bit more clue what your users will be mostly looking for and put only those links in the top navigation so they fit in nicely.**
For the rest of them you could develop a larger footer link menu where they could be presented in a simple list, in 2-3 columns. If possible, add search functionality to your website (at least through google).
Although, the current trends are moving away from large footers, in this website's case they would be an improvement in UX.

And you don't need the white text shadow on hover. Frankly, you need very little of the effects you currently have on your site.

TL; DR;

All in all, this page has too many of *bells and whistles* which, frankly, do not ad up to the total user experience. Your users get BOMBARDED with visual/cognitive input and if you asked me to recall what I remember from it after looking at it for 20 seconds, I could probably name 2-3 items. I was too amused by seeing resurrection of *blink* and *marquee* in 2014.

Yes, I understand that is not a typical western mindset website, but intended for web users in India. However, it is a governmental service website and you shouldn't be striving to show all the css/javascript tricks you have up your sleeve. **You are simply leaking away your users attention to things that do not matter.**

I would strongly suggest migrating to a more neutral color scheme.
Here's a sample list of health related webpages from few European country governments':

- [Netherlands](http://www.zorginstituutnederland.nl/)
- [Great Britain](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/department-of-health)
- [Germany](http://www.bmg.bund.de/ministerium/presse/english-version.html)
- [France](http://www.sante.gouv.fr/)

Also I hear India has a quite large smartphone user base. How are you optimizing for them? I don't see anything along the lines of responsiveness.

Comment: I'm not sure that he developed the original site. "I have got a work to recreate a website" implied to me that he has been tasked with redesigning it

Comment: this is the current view of website. @Harijs Deksnis i need to start modifying this. thanks for help... Mate

Comment: Pardon, I overlooked the recreate part :) Anyways, good luck with it!

Answer (score 1):

I would entertain thinking slightly differently and exploring a vertical side navbar. Perhaps, provide some organization to the navigation links. Two or three categories may help the user better digest your offered nav topics. Also, the text does not need a shadow, the white on dark blue pops for pleasant reading. I hope this helps.